# Can work done ever be negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, conventions

If a car is moving towards me and I push against the bonnet with a force $F$, but it makes little difference so the car pushes me backwards in a straight line for distance $x$, have I done $-Fx$ work on the car or have I done no work on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of negative work as if you were pulling energy *out* of the system. In your example, you are indeed trying to brake the car and you do that by removing $W=-Fx$ Joules from it's kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

The force that the car applies on you has a displacement which is in the same direction as the force so that force due to the car does positive work on you.

The force that you applied on the car has a displacement which is in the opposite direction to the force so that force due to you does negative work on the car.

Answer (score 1):

*Negative* work means that the object is *being done work **on***, as opposed to *doing* work.

Comment: Actually, the opposite is also true, it depends on what you take your system to be.